# Responsive checkbox align label with new line

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I need some help with the style of this checkbox, when I resize the window to adjust to mobile, the text label makes a line break, and checkbox just stills in his original position, how can I make to adjust the box align closer to his label? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```js
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" (change)="termsAndConditions($event.target)">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Acepto los <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/demodemodemo" target="_blank"><b>Términos y condiciones</b></a></label>
  </div>
```

CSS of container

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column; 
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

#formContent {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 450px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 30px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="formContent">
    <h2 style="cursor: pointer" routerLink="/login"  routerLinkActive="active"> Iniciar sesión </h2>
    <h2 style="cursor: pointer" routerLink="/signup"  routerLinkActive="active"> Crear cuenta </h2>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? Maybe some CSS?

Comment: sure, post updated

Comment: can you try with padding-left: 0!important; on div class="custom-control"

Comment: @sonEtLumiere can you post even more html and CSS?  Your provided HTML doesn't correlate to your CSS at all.

Comment: How about these two classes? `custom-control-input` `custom-control-label`

Comment: sure, i will post more code, custom-control it's just bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you shared and the behavior are different, here is what you can look into:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/87xt9czq/46/) to play around

here is how it looks for mobile screen.

[image]

```css
.custom-checkbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" (change)="termsAndConditions($event.target)">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Acepto los <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/demodemodemo" target="_blank"><b>Términos y condiciones</b></a></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm still having the same issue, maybe the css of wrapper and formContent are the problem

Comment: @sonEtLumiere `wrapper` and `form-content` class both doesn't exists in the snippet you shared and with the bit of code and understanding I have come up with an example just to show you can fix the issue like this, so either you can share the complete recreatable code so that we can look at it or you can take this as an example and implement in your work.

Comment: Manjuboyz code updated,it's Angular code, thanks for your help

Comment: @sonEtLumiere new HTML code doesn't have the checkbox control, which is the right one to use?

Comment: <router-outlet> equals the first html snippet that contains the checkbox, i think the problem is that text-center in #formContent class

Comment: can you confirm if this works for you https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/87xt9czq/52/

Comment: your code seems to works fine, but idk it doesn't work in my app, i'm checking, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution for now is by using @media and limit max-width of label, this is compatible with the text-align: center of the container

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 345px) {  
  .custom-control-label{
    max-width: 120px;
  }
}
```